# Download Curve in the past via TIA Bloomberg in Python

Tags: programming, market-data, bloomberg

I am using TIA package in Python to download an interest rate curve.
Using the following script I get the last curve.
How do I specify a date in the past to have a curve in the past?

```
import tia.bbg.datamgr as dm
curve="YCSW0045 Index"
mgr = dm.BbgDataManager()
msft=mgr[curve]
msft["CURVE_TENOR_RATES"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will NOT work.
You cannot get `ICVS` curves in API. Excel has a curves toolkit for excel. However, for `WAPI`, you need enterprise licenses (not part of terminal subscription). Your account manager can help you with that if that is truly needed.

What you do here, is simply a FLDS field. Check out `YCSW0045 Index FLDS CURVE_TENOR_RATES` on the terminal. You will see that the field description shows that only current value is available.

Side note, I would say that is not the best way to ask this. Use the help desk. They will most certainly not help with a 3rd party wrapper (I never used this one, but is this only [Python 2.7](https://github.com/bpsmith/tia)?). However, always ask how this works in excel (it's both c++ according to [Bloomberg](https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/)). I am sure it will not have taken almost 6 months for BBG to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

A variation of this can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47521574/tia-bloomberg-historical-request-with-overrides-python).
Try this..

```
import pandas as pd
import tia.bbg.datamgr as dm
mgr = dm.BbgDataManager()
curve='YCSW0045 Index'
sids = mgr[curve]
info_df = sids.get_historical(
['PX_LAST'],
       start="1/1/2000",
       end="6/30/2016",
       period="DAILY"
)
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion with the field and dates I need, but I get an empty dataframe (I do not even get the last value of the curve). Here the modified code:
sids.get_historical(
["CURVE_TENOR_RATES"],
       start="01/01/2020",
       end="12/01/2020",
       period="DAILY"
)